# issue with function gsub

Tags: r, string

```
> gsub('$', ' ' ,"$170,000")
[1] "$170,000 "
> gsub(',', ' ' ,"$170,000")
[1] "$170 000"
```

Why is the first output not " 170,000" ?

Comment: $ is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped. Just lke (, ^, | and others.

Comment: `gsub` uses regular expressions, so `$` has a specific meaning. Well, lots of things have a specific meaning with regular expressions. For your behavior, specify `fixed = TRUE`, because then it will just grab the $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to `escape` `$`:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\$", replacement = " ", x = "$170,000")

" 170,000"
```

For more info about `escape`: [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)